loading image with react suspense once loading fully completed
I need to load the image once the image preload is fully completed using React Suspense, the issue is that "onLoad" event on  triggers when image starts loading not once its completed. here is the implementation. createResource is a functions that makes a suspender to be used for Suspense component in react

const loadImage = (src: string) => {
  let resource = cache.get(src);
  if (resource) {
    return resource;
  }
  resource = createResource(
    () =>
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const img = new window.Image();
        img.src = src;
        img.onload = () => {
          resolve(img);
        };
        img.onerror = error => {
          reject(error);
        };
      })
  );
  cache.set(src, resource);
  return resource;
};

const Image = (src) => {
 const image = loadImage(src).read()
 <img src={image.src} />
}


Try this component
interface ImageWithLoadingProps {
  src: string;
  alt: string;
}

const ImageWithLoading: React.FC<ImageWithLoadingProps> = ({ src, alt }) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = src;
    img.onload = () => setLoading(false); // This is called when the image has finished loading
  }, [src]);

  return (
    <div>
      {loading ? (
        <div>Loading...</div>
      ) : (
        <img src={src} alt={alt} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};


img.complete is a boolean not event handler, so when being used in a promise it never resolves the promise. could you explain how it could be used in above promise?
